# Random SSL errors in iOS 8.1. (NSURLErrorDomain:-1200)

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, nsurlconnection, ios8.1

In iOS 8.1 we are getting random SSL errors.

There is no issue at the sever and it seems like iOS device issue. AWS support has checked the SSL configuration and the certificate in server, but didn't find any issue.

Error message is this - "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. (NSURLErrorDomain:-1200)". We are using NSURLConnection to make network connections.

Many of our users started getting this error recently and all were in in iOS 8.1. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue with iOS8.1 user on my website
on the server side, i have this error :

No hostname was provided via SNI for a name based virtual host

it seems that iOS8.1 doesn't support very well SNI.

The workaround is to configure your webserver tp accept client that doesn't support SNI and set the virtualhost and certificate you want "no SNI client" to be show by default for any all SSL virtualhosts

In apache you have to add :

NameVirtualHost *.443 #before the first SSL virtualhost which will have the default certificate.

SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off # in this default virtualhost.

Sorry for my english (i'm french) and hope it will help